How do I add a user with "Full Control" permissions to folder without changing owner of the folder (I.E.) Administrators, using the command line?
I want a command-line solution to add a local user account to the permissions table for a directory and grant the account full access... WITHOUT changing the ownership of the directory.
I'm looking for the equivilent of this:


I want to do this programmatically in the command line using either PWSH or CMD. Preferrably Powershell 7.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Do you know when you give Full Control that this allows those with that permission to change the ACLs/permissions of those to something else technically? You should never give non-admins full control, you should give them Modify. Otherwise, if you notice the ACL permission change after you set it, that may be why because you gave them permission to go in there and make any ACL security adjustments themselves.

This is a personal computer. The user I want to give full permissions to is my own personal account (Already part of the Administrators group). The reason why I want to do this is so that I don't get security dialogs when I try to copy file to some subfolder of "Program Files", or try to create new files in some subdirectory of "Program Files". Despite the fact my user account belongs to the Administrator role, it still gives me grief when I'm doing things inside certain folders. So I just wanted a quick way to give myself full access. (Continued in next comment)

The command I settled on to give permissions is icacls <directory> /grant:r <username>:(OI)(CI)F /c and the command to revoke is takeown /f <directory> /a /r /d y and then icacls <directory> /remove <username> /t /c
I created a couple powershell scripts based on this and then assigned them to new entries in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell registry key, so now I can just right click a folder and grant myself access or revoke and reset to administrators.
